# How to withdraw eth from the contract in zksync

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js, ethers.js

I want to withdraw eth from the contract in Zksync.
The withdrawal with solidity code is as follows. And this code is successful in goerli but failed in zksync goerli.

```
function withdraw(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        require(amount <= address(this).balance, "Not enough funds in the contract");
        
        // Update state before transferring
        uint256 toTransfer = amount;
        recipient.transfer(toTransfer);
    }
```

Following is my ts code to run withdraw method, but it's not successful.

```
import { Provider } from "zksync-web3";
import * as ethers from "ethers";
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";

// load env file
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

// load contract artifact. Make sure to compile first!
import * as ContractArtifact from "../artifacts-zk/contracts/MinterFactory.sol/MinterFactory.json";

const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY || "";

if (!PRIVATE_KEY)
  throw "⛔️ Private key not detected! Add it to the .env file!";

// Address of the contract on zksync testnet
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "";

if (!CONTRACT_ADDRESS) throw "⛔️ Contract address not provided";

// An example of a deploy script that will deploy and call a simple contract.
export default async function (hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment) {
  console.log(`Running script to interact with contract ${CONTRACT_ADDRESS}`);

  // Initialize the provider.
  // @ts-ignore
  const provider = new Provider(hre.userConfig.networks?.zkSyncTestnet?.url);
  const signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

  // Initialize contract instance
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(
    CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    ContractArtifact.abi,
    signer
  );

  // Read a message from contract
//   console.log(`The message is ${await contract.greet()}`);

  // send transaction to update the message
  const newMessage = "Hello people!";
  const amount = ethers.utils.parseEther('0.0001')
  console.log('amount',amount)
  // const estimatedGas = await contract.estimateGas.withdraw('', amount);
  // console.log(estimatedGas)
  const tx = await contract.withdraw('', 500000000000000, {
    gasLimit: 5000000  //
  });

  console.log(`Transaction to change the message is ${tx.hash}`);
  await tx.wait();

  // Read message after the transaction
//   console.log(`The message now is ${await contract.greet()}`);
}
```

I have already run the TS script above using hardhat and it failed.

I have also run this function on Goerli using the Remix editor and the result is successful.

The exception is as follows

```
Running a script to interact with contract 0xF0514AEFA1A60B5451a7DfB587ced79aeCF53ecf
amount BigNumber { _hex: '0x5af3107a4000', _isBigNumber: true }
Transaction to change the message is 0xc7fa95c3653293f21995bfc7e3b1a76baf01bbb8336a18d7e3b6b4a55dae8cfd
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (transactionHash="0xc7fa95c3653293f21995bfc7e3b1a76baf01bbb8336a18d7e3b6b4a55dae8cfd", transaction={"type":2,"chainId":280,"nonce":31,"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x77359400"},"gasPrice":null,"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x4c4b40"},"to":"0xF0514AEFA1A60B5451a7DfB587ced79aeCF53ecf","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"data":"0xf3fef3a30000000000000000000000004db37fb3bfbe7f37ec14fccfc163f7cb587a73570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c6bf52634000","accessList":[],"hash":"0xc7fa95c3653293f21995bfc7e3b1a76baf01bbb8336a18d7e3b6b4a55dae8cfd","v":0,"r":"0x6a053079644d78dba48c105a19efa93d4c0adbb3f6ce3677e27ee7846d809800","s":"0x5a4b15cdc1515e0c06f5674f8b77baad1505cf8958e2fa9c5d60a2478c1331cc","from":"0x4DB37FB3BFBE7F37eC14FcCfc163F7CB587A7357","confirmations":0}, receipt={"to":"0xF0514AEFA1A60B5451a7DfB587ced79aeCF53ecf","from":"0x4DB37FB3BFBE7F37eC14FcCfc163F7CB587A7357","contractAddress":null,"transactionIndex":0,"root":"0x98129cfc04732939eb7682837765da7665c03e82e92ac2c4d2fe008de9c31c2d","gasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x02e43a"},"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","blockHash":"0x98129cfc04732939eb7682837765da7665c03e82e92ac2c4d2fe008de9c31c2d","transactionHash":"0xc7fa95c3653293f21995bfc7e3b1a76baf01bbb8336a18d7e3b6b4a55dae8cfd","logs":[{"transactionIndex":0,"blockNumber":10774592,"transactionHash":"0xc7fa95c3653293f21995bfc7e3b1a76baf01bbb8336a18d7e3b6b4a55dae8cfd","address":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000800A","topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000004db37fb3bfbe7f37ec14fccfc163f7cb587a7357","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008001"],"data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000","logIndex":0,"blockHash":"0x98129cfc04732939eb7682837765da7665c03e82e92ac2c4d2fe008de9c31c2d"},{"transactionIndex":0,"blockNumber":10774592,"transactionHash":"0xc7fa95c3653293f21995bfc7e3b1a76baf01bbb8336a18d7e3b6b4a55dae8cfd","address":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000800A","topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008001","0x0000000000000000000000004db37fb3bfbe7f37ec14fccfc163f7cb587a7357"],"data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f161421c8e000","logIndex":1,"blockHash":"0x98129cfc04732939eb7682837765da7665c03e82e92ac2c4d2fe008de9c31c2d"},{"transactionIndex":0,"blockNumber":10774592,"transactionHash":"0xc7fa95c3653293f21995bfc7e3b1a76baf01bbb8336a18d7e3b6b4a55dae8cfd","address":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000800A","topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008001","0x0000000000000000000000004db37fb3bfbe7f37ec14fccfc163f7cb587a7357"],"data":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000445c811b9af00","logIndex":2,"blockHash":"0x98129cfc04732939eb7682837765da7665c03e82e92ac2c4d2fe008de9c31c2d"}],"blockNumber":10774592,"confirmations":1,"cumulativeGasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"effectiveGasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x0ee6b280"},"status":0,"type":2,"l2ToL1Logs":[],"byzantium":true}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/kingnet/zksync/ssling/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/kingnet/zksync/ssling/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
    at Provider.<anonymous> (/home/kingnet/zksync/ssling/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/src.ts/base-provider.ts:1549:24)
    at step (/home/kingnet/zksync/ssling/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (/home/kingnet/zksync/ssling/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/kingnet/zksync/ssling/node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib/base-provider.js:20:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: 'transaction failed',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  transactionHash: '0xc7fa95c3653293f21995bfc7e3b1a76baf01bbb8336a18d7e3b6b4a55dae8cfd',
  transaction: {
    type: 2,
    chainId: 280,
    nonce: 31,
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x77359400', _isBigNumber: true },
    gasPrice: null,
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x4c4b40', _isBigNumber: true },
    to: '0xF0514AEFA1A60B5451a7DfB587ced79aeCF53ecf',
    value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
    data: '0xf3fef3a30000000000000000000000004db37fb3bfbe7f37ec14fccfc163f7cb587a73570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c6bf52634000',
    accessList: [],
    hash: '0xc7fa95c3653293f21995bfc7e3b1a76baf01bbb8336a18d7e3b6b4a55dae8cfd',
    v: 0,
    r: '0x6a053079644d78dba48c105a19efa93d4c0adbb3f6ce3677e27ee7846d809800',
    s: '0x5a4b15cdc1515e0c06f5674f8b77baad1505cf8958e2fa9c5d60a2478c1331cc',
    from: '0x4DB37FB3BFBE7F37eC14FcCfc163F7CB587A7357',
    confirmations: 0,
    wait: [Function (anonymous)],
    waitFinalize: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)]
  },
  receipt: {
    to: '0xF0514AEFA1A60B5451a7DfB587ced79aeCF53ecf',
    from: '0x4DB37FB3BFBE7F37eC14FcCfc163F7CB587A7357',
    contractAddress: null,
    transactionIndex: 0,
    root: '0x98129cfc04732939eb7682837765da7665c03e82e92ac2c4d2fe008de9c31c2d',
    gasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0x02e43a', _isBigNumber: true },
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    blockHash: '0x98129cfc04732939eb7682837765da7665c03e82e92ac2c4d2fe008de9c31c2d',
    transactionHash: '0xc7fa95c3653293f21995bfc7e3b1a76baf01bbb8336a18d7e3b6b4a55dae8cfd',
    logs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    blockNumber: 10774592,
    confirmations: 1,
    cumulativeGasUsed: BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true },
    effectiveGasPrice: BigNumber { _hex: '0x0ee6b280', _isBigNumber: true },
    status: 0,
    type: 2,
    l2ToL1Logs: [],
    byzantium: true
  }
}
```